# React Native Navigation v1 Android blank Screen

Tags: android, react-native

To reproduce this - I created a new react native project with react-native init - version 0.55.4

Everything works perfectly. run-android and run-ios

I add react-native-navigation - don't link it to native - everything works perfectly.

Link the project according to the instructions - I don't even add navigation code or any code - it's still the default App.js React Native app. And it doesn't load the JS - ios works - it loads the usual React Native default screen.

Most of the questions I have seen have had other errors in the js code that cause the white screen - mine has no extra code to error - all I have added is the library and linked it to android.

I have had this library working on RN 0.47.x but then I can't get facebook fbsdk login to work so I need to upgrade my project to latest RN.

I've added logs to android to the react native navigation files but I can't really see where it's breaking.

I don't think it's the timing bug - makes no difference if I reload the app from the small apps screen  (from the little square menu -  from apps running in the background). It just never shows anything other than the blank screen and no errors anywhere - doesn't load the chrome debugger, nothing in logcat.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Commenting because I don't have a proper solution however you can disable remote js debugging on the emulator / device. Then run `react-native run-android`. The app should now build properly, then you can enable js debugging again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the react-native version 0.55, it works fine on version 0.49.